# Postgres timestamp field not showing microseconds component when value is all zeros

Tags: postgresql, psql

Context: I'm using Postgres 9.3 and psql (PostgreSQL) 11.1.

Given the following table:

```sql
create table ts_test(ts timestamp);
```

The following insert commands display time with microsecond granularity:

```sql
INSERT INTO ts_test
VALUES
    (now()),
    (TIMESTAMP '2019-03-06 20:18:41.000001');
```

```sql
select * from ts_test;
             ts
----------------------------
 2019-03-06 20:40:35.062547
 2019-03-06 20:18:41.000001
```

However, when a timestamp with all zeroes as the microsecond component is inserted, I observe the following behavior:

```sql
INSERT INTO ts_test VALUES (TIMESTAMP '2019-03-06 20:18:41.000000');
```

```sql
select * from ts_test;
             ts
----------------------------
 2019-03-06 20:40:35.062547
 2019-03-06 20:18:41.000001
 2019-03-06 20:18:41
```

I've pored over the documentation, but am drawing a total blank as to why the microseconds are omitted from the third entry.

Comment: Aside, Postgres 9.3 reached EOL in November 2018. Consider upgrading: https://www.postgresql.org/support/versioning/ psql is only the command-line terminal.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`TIMESTAMP '2019-03-06 20:18:41.000000'` and `TIMESTAMP '2019-03-06 20:18:41'` are *identical values*. All-zero fractional digits, that's just insignificant noise which is not stored in the data type `timestamp` (internally an 8-byte integer).

If you want to preserve original literals including all noise, insignificant zeros and white space, you'll have to store it in a string type like `text`.

If you want to *display* timestamps with microseconds you might use [`to_char()` with the template pattern `US`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-formatting.html#FUNCTIONS-FORMATTING-DATETIME-TABLE):

```
select to_char(ts, 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS:US') AS ts1 from ts_test;
             ts1
----------------------------
 2019-03-06 20:40:35.062547
 2019-03-06 20:18:41.000001
 2019-03-06 20:18:41.000000  -- !
```

This result is `text`, of course. (Use the pattern `MS` for milliseconds.)